# QNX runtime error: unknown symbol __stack_chk_guard

Tags: runtime-error, backwards-compatibility, buffer-overflow, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I'm trying to test the backward compatibility between QNX 6.6.0 and 6.5.0 (in concequence of an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460288/whats-the-difference-between-qnx-6-5-1-and-6-6-0-backwards-compatibility) I've got). I compiled a relatively simple program using SDP6.6.0 and executed it on Neutrino 6.5.0. When I execute the program the follow runtime error pops up:

> unknown symbol: __stack_chk_guard
>
> ldd:FATAL: Could not resolve all symbols

What is causing this?..

---

*(I've found the solution but it wasn't working rightaway. When I started writing this question I realized the error I made. For future reference I will provide the solution here as Q&A myself).*

Answer (score 1):

Since QNX is using gcc (qcc):

"Buffer overflow detection is enabled in the current and newer gcc builds however in some (rare and complex) cases this may result in run time complications such as undefined symbol: `__stack_chk_guard` errors. In such cases a possible solution is to disable this feature by adding `-fno-stack-protector` to the `CFLAG` list used by gcc compilation options" (see also [[1](https://www.sharcnet.ca/help/index.php/GCC)] and [What is the use of -fno-stack-protector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712972/what-is-the-use-of-fno-stack-protector)).

Additionally: I found a forum [thread](http://community.qnx.com/sf/discussion/do/listPosts/projects.toolchain/discussion.core_development_tools.topc25678) where Ryan Mansfield (QNX compiler lead maintainer, I think) says:

> One problem [one] might hit trying to get 6.6.0 binaries to run on 6.5.0, 
>   is that everything is built is with `-fstack-protector`, which relies on 
>   support in *libc*. This wasn't in the 6.5.0 *libc* but IIRC, 6.5.0SP1 added.

Thus, in QNX 6.5.0SP1 this issue seems to be fixed.